# How do I print all posible substrings of a given string?

Tags: c++

After the first iteration of the first for loop, it is not printing the correct answer. Can someone fix my problem?

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <string>    
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string s="ABCD";
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        for(int j=i; j<s.length(); j++) {
            string s1(s,i,j+1);
            cout<<s1<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To make it easier for answerers, or others with similar problems, please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: When you used the debugger, which statement is causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the code into

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <string>    
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string s="ABCD";
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        for(int j=1; j<=s.length()-i; j++) {
            string s1(s,i,j); //get a substring of s from position with length j
        cout<<s1<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You didn't specify much as to what the problem was, but I'm going to assume you want something like

```
A
AB
ABC
ABCD
B
BC
BCD
C
CD
D
```

to output, and in that case, you've limited it backwards. Instead of making the inner loop start at where the outer is, make it go for only as long as it needs to.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string s="ABCD";
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<s.length() - i; j++) {
            string s1(s,i,j+1);
            cout<<s1<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```